# Using Python Selenium Not able to perform click operation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, selenium3, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am automating for the following page on CHROME Browser

```
https://study.yupl.us/studies/5d5a64aa8b5bb92fb776753b?auth=false
```

Here I'm able to identify the unique element from the console for the XPATH used

```
$x('//button[text()="START STUDY"]')
```

But when the same code is integrated with the script and run.

Integrated Script -

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

driver = Chrome('/Users/downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://study.yupl.us/studies/5d5a64aa8b5bb92fb776753b?auth=false')
driver.maximize_window()

sleep(8)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="START STUDY"]').click()
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/Practice/t.py", line 54, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="START STUDY"]').click()
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/Study/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/Study/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/Study/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/Study/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="ui button" role="button" style="background-color: rgb(31, 186, 238); color: white; border-radius: 0px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600; line-height: 20px; text-align: center; width: 200px; height: 50px; margin-top: 26px;">...</button> is not clickable at point (1047, 320). Other element would receive the click: <div>...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
```

I have tried to click on the element using the ActionChains class as well. Even then the same issue is got

Comment: Looks like the element that you wanted to perform a click on is obscured by another element. I believe you would have already verified the state of the element before the click; Things you can consider doing is perform a wait and may be maximize the window/scroll to the element which ever is applicable.

Answer (score 7):

Try using JavaScriptExecutor

C#

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@role='button']"));
IJavaScriptExecutor jse2 = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jse2.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Python

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@role='button']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: This is the only way I got the "click" working in my Python code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Reason**:
This is a known issue for some time now.
`https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/search?q=ElementClickInterceptedException&type=Issues`
This exception suggests that there is another element (div below the button) will receive the click.

**Solutions:**

1. Use another locator

2. Use Javascript executor
`driver.execute_script(JSCode,arguments)`

e.g. driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
Takes your locator (element) as first argument and perform the action of click.

This action is equivalent to JQuery: `$(locator).click`

Comment: Great answer, @Sameer Wakude ! Thank you !